# How to mv using sed to rename files with trailing space?

Tags: bash, sed

We have a very large file structure that has been very badly built. Paths contain lots of spaces, @, spaces around dashes.

It's all hosted on a Synology NAS, so I don't have access to the whole array of tools usually included (like `rename`).

I'm trying to rename file AND folder names that have a leading and trailing spaces.

```sh
# Global vars
tstamp=$(date +%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S)

# Change for separator to newline
IFS=$'\n'

echo "$tstamp - Renaming files with leading space: \n"

for filename in $(find . -type f -name '[[:space:]]*')
do
newFilename=$(echo $filename |sed 's/\/[[:space:]]/\//g')
        echo "original: $filename"
        echo "new     : $newFilename"
        mv -i -v -n $filename $newFilename
        echo "\n"
done

echo "$tstamp - Renaming files with trailing space: \n"

for filename in $(find . -type f -name '*[[:space:]]')
do
newFilename=$(echo $filename |sed 's/[[:space:]]$//g')
        echo "original: $filename"
        echo "new     : $newFilename"
        mv -i -v -n $filename $newFilename
        echo "\n"
done


# A slash "/" in a filename is not possible thus it's not verified
echo "$tstamp - Renaming files with unsupported characters (\ / \" : < > ; | * ?):"

for filename in $(find . -type f -name '*\**' -o -name '*\\*' -o -name '*"*' -o -name '*:*' -o -name '*<*' -o -name '*>*' -o -name '*;*' -o -name '*|*' -o -name '*\?*')
do
newFilename=$(echo $filename |sed 's/\(\\\|"\|:\|<\|>\|;\||\|\*\|\?\)//g')
        echo "original: $filename"
        echo "new     : $newFilename"
        mv -i -v -n $filename $newFilename
        echo "\n"
done

echo "Done."

#EOF
```

Renaming files with unsupported characters works well, but not the leading and trainling spaces.

Here's an actual output where I replaced some names for security purposes:

original:

`./ABC- Financing/2018 - ABC Capital Bl Fund 2018 (VCCI)/0 - Dataroom/8 - Vérification diligente/3. Governance/ 2017Q1/ Documents de Julie/@eaDir/ PPP@SynoResource`

new:

`./ABC - Financing/2018 - ABC Capital Innovation Fund 2018 (GGGG)/0 - Dataroom/8 - Vérification diligente/3. Governance/2017Q1/Documents de Julie/@eaDir/PPP@SynoResource`

`./ABC - Financing/2018 - ABC Capital Innovation Fund 2018 (GGGG)/0 - Dataroom/8 - Vérification diligente/3. Governance/ 2017Q1/ Documents de Julie/@eaDir/ CDP@SynoResource` → `./ABC - Financing/2018 - ABC Capital Innovation Fund 2018 (GGGG)/0 - Dataroom/8 - Vérification diligente/3. Governance/2017Q1/Documents de Julie/@eaDir/PPP@SynoResource`

`mv: cannot move "./ABC - Financing/2018 - ABC Capital Innovation Fund 2018 (GGGG)/0 - Dataroom/8 - Vérification diligente/3. Governance/ 2017Q1/ Documents de Julie/@eaDir/ PPP@SynoResource" to "./ABC - Financing/2018 - ABC Capital Innovation Fund 2018 (GGGG)/0 - Dataroom/8 - Vérification diligente/3. Governance/2017Q1/Documents de Julie/@eaDir/PPP@SynoResource": No such file or directory`

I don't understand why the file isn't found by the mv command.

Comment: use * if you have any special characters and try the mv command

Comment: It is wise to doublequote all variables referenced or used on the RHS in your script. Also see http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html .  So `mv -i -v -n "$filename" "$newFilename"`, `echo "$filename"` etc.

Comment: "put the entire file name inside double quote otherwise.csv"

Comment: Btw., instead of `echo "\n"`, you can just use `echo`.

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001. Which bash version are you running (`bash --version`)?

Comment: @Roadowl, please don't link the ABS -- it's notorious for showcasing bad practices in its examples. [The Wooledge BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) was written *specifically* as a response to the ABS's quality issues.

Comment: @Charles Duffy  Thanks, I stand corrected. I didn't know that at all.

Answer (score 1):

Start with this (uses GNU versions of find and sed):

```
#/bin/env bash

readarray -d '' paths < <(find . -depth -print0)
for old in "${paths[@]}"; do
     printf 'Working on path %q\n' "$old" >&2
     new=$(
         printf '%s' "$old" |
         sed -z '
             s#[\\":<>;|*?]##g
             s#[[:space:]]*/[[:space:]]*#/#g
             s#[[:space:]]*$##
         '
     )
     if [[ "$new" != "$old" ]]; then
         printf 'old: %q\n' "$old" >&2
         printf 'new: %q\n' "$new" >&2
         [[ -f "$new" ]] && printf 'Warning: %q already exists.\n' "$new" >&2
         mv -i -v -n -- "$old" "$new"
         printf '\n'
     fi
done
```

You can probably replace the `printf | sed` with some bash builtins for a performance improvement but life's too short for me to try to figure that out and the above should be clear and simple enough for any other changes you need to make.

The above is untested so make sure you take a backup of your files and test it thoroughly on a temp dir before running on your real files.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to add a test for name collision between `$new` and existing files: `if [[ -f $new ]]; then Add/Increment a Digit in the Filename; fi`

Comment: Have to do depth-first

Comment: Or `find -depth`. The `-n` for `mv` just bails if there's a collision.

Comment: Yup find -depth would do it and then I can remove the pipe to sort, thx. Right on the `-n` but the OP has that and `-i` to deal with it in their existing code and IMHO if they want to handle that differently they can massage to suit.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson I added a warning for an existing file. Doesn't hurt :-).

Comment: Better to use `printf 'Old: %q\n' "$old"`; that way nonprintable characters are rendered readably &c.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy fair enough I've done that for all logging printfs (i.e. all except the pipe to sed).

Comment: Removing prohibited characters last may lead to naked leading or trailing spaces. This is why you should move the prohibited characters deletion rule as the first rule in your `sed` script.

Answer (score 0):

Lets try to do it safely and correctly this way instead:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

shopt -s extglob # setup extended globbing so it can match group multipe times

# Find all files or directories names that:
# either starts with spaces,
# or ends with spaces,
# or contains any of the \ " : < > ; | * ? prohibited characters
find . \
  -depth \
  \( -type f -or -type d \) \
  -regextype posix-extended \
  -regex '.*/([[:space:]].*|.*[[:space:]]|.*[\\":<>;|*?].*)' \
  -print0 \
  | while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do

    # Isolates the file name from its directory path
    base="$(basename -- "${filename}")"

    # ExtGlob strips-out all instances of prohibited characters class using //
    # [\\\":<>;|*?]
    base="${base//[\\\":<>;|*?]/}"

    # ExtGlob strips-out leading spaces
    # *([[:space:]]):
    # * 0 or any times the following (group)
    # [[:space:]] any space character
    base="${base/*([[:space:]])/}"

    # ExtGlob strips-out trailing spaces using %%
    base="${base%%*([[:space:]])}"

    # Compose a new file name from the new base
    newFilename="$(dirname -- "${filename}")/${base}"

    # Prevent the new file name to collide with existing files
    # by adding a versionned suffix
    suffix=''
    count=1
    while [[ -e "${newFilename}${suffix}" ]]; do
      suffix=".$((count++))"
    done
    newFilename="${newFilename}${suffix}"

    printf \
      "original: '%s'\\nnew     : '%s'\\n\\n" \
      "${filename}" \
      "${newFilename}"
    mv -- "${filename}" "${newFilename}"

  done

echo 'Done.'
```

Comment: I'd generally avoid `echo -e`, as POSIX doesn't specify `echo`'s behavior when backslashes are present in arguments, and bash itself can implement `-e` different ways (including just printing the string as literal output) depending on current runtime flag state. See Stephane's excellent [unix.se] answer on the topic at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/3113

Comment: ...the only other thing that strikes me as a pending/outstanding robustness fix would be using `--` as an end-of-options sigil, to prevent a file named `-foo` from being interpreted as an option rather than an argument. (See POSIX utility syntax guidelines entry #10 at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html). Granted, here, `find` will always prefix names with `./`, so that shouldn't be a risk if the later code is only used in context of such a command.